# How can we interpret this Python code?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I came across the following code snippet:

```
output = numpy.zeros((max(img1.shape[0], img2.shape[0]), img1.shape[1] + img2.shape[1], img1.shape[2]), dtype=img1.dtype)
output[:img1.shape[0], :img1.shape[1],:] = img1
output[:img2.shape[0]:,img1.shape[1]:img1.shape[1]+img2.shape[1],:] = img2
```

I was able to understand the first line:

```
output = numpy.zeros((max(img1.shape[0], img2.shape[0]), img1.shape[1] + img2.shape[1], img1.shape[2]), dtype=img1.dtype)
```

But, couldn't interpret what the following two lines mean:

```
output[:img1.shape[0], :img1.shape[1],:] = img1
output[:img2.shape[0]:,img1.shape[1]:img1.shape[1]+img2.shape[1],:] = img2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for your kind support.

Comment: Those are numpy array indices.  `a[:b, :c, :]` takes a slice of array `a`, where the first index runs from 0 up to b, the second runs from 0 up to c, and the third is the entire slice of that dimension.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. What about this statement? :img2.shape[0]: (notice the ":" at the end).

Comment: I don't think that trailing colon has any effect.  It introduces a step for the range, which defaults to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, img1 and img2 are matrices containing all the pixels of two images.

Suppose:

```
img1 = x x x
       x x x
       x x x

img2 = o o
       o o
       o o
       o o
```

Output is a matrix whose height is the highest between img1 and img2 and whose width is the sum of both widths. I don't know if depth is relevant, but it uses the depth (z-axis) of the first image. Then output would be:

```
output = 0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0
```

The first step is to save img1 on output. This is done occupying the indices from 0 to img1.height on the y axis and from 0 to img1.width on the y axis.

```
output[:img1.shape[0], :img1.shape[1],:] = img1

output = x x x 0 0
         x x x 0 0
         x x x 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0
```

Next, img2 is saved from 0 to img2.height on the y axis and from img1.width to img1.width+img2.width on the x axis.

Then:

```
output[:img2.shape[0]:,img1.shape[1]:img1.shape[1]+img2.shape[1],:] = img2

output = x x x o o
         x x x o o
         x x x o o
         0 0 0 o o
```

I suppose that this would be done in the z axis as well if both images have information on this axis.

Comment: A very nice answer! Just a small note. Since I'm using "numpy", the first dimension is the height and the second dimension is the width. So, in your answer, you only need to replace width with height, and height with width. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, corrected! :-D

Answer (score 0):

It's stacking two images one next to the other. An example without the thrid dimension:

```
img1 = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1]])
img2 = np.array([[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]])
output = np.zeros((max(img1.shape[0], img2.shape[0]), img1.shape[1] + img2.shape[1]), dtype=img1.dtype)
output[:img1.shape[0], :img1.shape[1]] = img1
output[:img2.shape[0]:, img1.shape[1]:img1.shape[1] + img2.shape[1]] = img2
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 2 2 2]
 [1 1 2 2 2]
 [0 0 2 2 2]]
```

Since you are using `numpy` I recomend you to use [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) or [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html).